# Firebase functions not triggered to populate Firestore collection, even when the deployment is successful. Why?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I want a new doc to be added to my user collection which is triggered by firebase.auth() but the db is not getting populated.

This is my firebase function:

```
exports.newUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    return db
        .collection("user")
        .doc(user.uid)
        .create(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user)));
});
```

This is my registeration method:

```
export const register = (email, password) => dispatch => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(() => {
            resolve()
        })
        .catch(() => {
            console.log(typeof (email, password))
            reject()
        })
})
```

Upon execution the new user is added to Authentication but doesn't trigger the new document creation. The function newUser is successfully deployed to firebase.

Seems like my method of parsing user data is incorrect, please suggest what am I missing?

Function logs:

> 4:38:51.935 PM
> outlined_flag
> newUser
> Function execution started
> 4:38:52.968 PM
> newUser
> TypeError: entry.toJSON is not a function
> 4:38:52.968 PM
> newUser
> at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/identity.js:113:70
> 4:38:52.968 PM
> newUser
> at Array.map ()
> 4:38:52.968 PM
> newUser
> at Object.record.toJSON (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/identity.js:113:49)
> 4:38:52.968 PM
> newUser
> at JSON.stringify ()
> 4:38:52.968 PM
> newUser
> at /workspace/index.js:10:33
> 4:38:52.968 PM
> newUser
> at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:23)
> 4:38:52.968 PM
> newUser
> at /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/function_wrappers.js:144:25
> 4:38:52.968 PM
> newUser
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> 4:38:52.968 PM
> newUser
> TypeError: entry.toJSON is not a function
> 4:38:52.968 PM
> newUser
> at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/identity.js:113:70
> 4:38:52.968 PM
> newUser
> at Array.map ()
> 4:38:52.968 PM
> newUser
> at Object.record.toJSON (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/identity.js:113:49)
> 4:38:52.968 PM
> newUser
> at JSON.stringify ()
> more_vert
> 4:38:52.968 PM
> newUser
> at /workspace/index.js:10:33
> 4:38:52.968 PM
> newUser
> at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:23)
> 4:38:52.968 PM
> newUser
> at /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/function_wrappers.js:144:25
> 4:38:52.968 PM
> newUser
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> 4:38:52.979 PM
> outlined_flag
> newUser
> Function execution took 1044 ms. Finished with status: error

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: You have an error message that's split up into many different lines, and we can't see the whole thing in that screenshot.  It needs to be reassembled into a meaningful error message that describes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*firebaser here*

From what I can tell this bug was introduced into our Functions SDK recently. You can check its status on the Github repo issue [#1102](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/1102).

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

I tried this function and it does the job:

```
exports.newUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    return db
        .collection("user")
        .doc(user.uid)
        .set({
            email: user.email,
            createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
            updatedAt: new Date().toISOString()
        })
});
```